# Is there an alternative to Object.assign performance wise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I was wondering if there is an alternative to `Object.assign`. The problem that I am experiencing is that `Object.assign` is a bit slow when I am streaming data via websocket. Let me know.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { normalize } from 'normalizr';
import { tweetSchema } from '../store/Schema/tweet.js';

const initialState = () => ({
  byTweetId: {},
  byUserId: {},
  allTweetIds: [],
});

// action, actionTypes and reducer
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'tweets',
  initialState: initialState(),
  // reducers
  reducers: {
    tweetAdded: (state, action) => {
      const { entities, result } = normalize(action.payload, tweetSchema);
      Object.assign(state.byTweetId, entities.byTweetId);
      Object.assign(state.byUserId, entities.byUserId);
      state.allTweetIds.push(result);
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to `Object.assign` we have spread operator `...`
and it's faster than `Object.assign` for some use cases but it totally depends upon the size of the data as well on the cpu, I think there is just a miner difference between these two.

[Benchmarks](https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2136/0/javascript-spread-operator-vs-objectassign-performance) results may differ from the below results
[image]

**Sample Data:**

```js
const firstObject = { sampleData: 'Hello world' }
const secondObject = { moreData: 'foo bar' }
const finalObjectSpread = {
    ...firstObject,
    ...secondObject
};



const finalObjectAsign = Object.assign(firstObject, secondObject);

console.log("Object.assign ", finalObjectSpread);
console.log("Spread operator ", finalObjectSpread)
```

Comment: The two codes that this benchmarks compares don't even do the same, so it's pretty meaningless.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean by  ```don't even do the same```, because the sample data used for both is the same.

Comment: The object literal (with spread) creates a third object, `Object.assign` does not. (And of course, [don't trust microbenchmarks in general](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html))

Comment: @Bergi +1  nice catch ```Object.assign``` is mutating the original one, but when we do performance test then we focus on the ```results``` generated by different algo and every algo take different approaches and of course each algo has some pros and cons, that's right microbenchmarks are not trusted results but we can assume avg result for some use cases.